# Can't call custom css in style.php

Tags: css

I am using SMOF options to control variables in the backend. As it is just now I have the css options being generated in the header file and they work, however I wish to add them to a style.php.

I have set this up however the variable data is not being displayed and the css options are empty.i.e

```
.site-header, .header-bar {
            background-image:URL('');
```

I presume it is the `global $data;` call that is incorrect. How would I fix this?

Style.php

```
/* Body Styling */
body {
    background:<?php global $data; echo $data['body_background'];?>;
    background-image:url(<?php global $data; echo $data['body_background_background']; ?>);
    background-repeat:repeat;
}

a {
    color:<?php global $data; echo $data['link_color'];?>;
}

a:hover {
    color:<?php global $data; echo $data['link_color_hover'];?>;
}

html,body {
    font-family:<?php global $data; $arraytype = $data['typography_body']; $stringtype=implode(",",$arraytype); echo $stringtype;?>; 
    color:<?php global $data; echo $data['font_color_select'];?>;
    font-size:<?php global $data; echo $data['font_size_select'];?>;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4 {
    font-family:<?php global $data; $arrayheading = $data['typography_h1']; $stringheading=implode(",",$arrayheading); echo $stringheading; ?>
}

/* General Styling */
.singlebutton,.tags-button a,.contactbutton input,#commentsubmit,.btn-standard-blog,.search-submit {
    background-color:<?php global $data; echo $data['button_color_select'];?>;
    color:<?php global $data; echo $data['button_color_text'];?>;
}

.singlebutton:hover,.tags-button a:hover,.contactbutton input:hover,#commentsubmit:hover,.btn-standard-blog:hover,.search-submit:hover {
    background-color:<?php global $data; echo $data['button_color_hover'];?>;
    color:<?php global $data; echo $data['button_color_text'];?>;
}
```

**FUNCTIONS.php**

...

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'albaband-dynam-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/css/style.php' );
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to add dynamic CSS is to put it inside a callback and hook the callback into the template, e.g. via `wp_head` (or `wp_print_styles`).

You've not posted your code in full context, so you will need to modify to suit your specific needs. That said, here's the basic principle:

### Callback

```
function wpse_129259_enqueue_dynamic_css() {
    // Grab your variable
    global $data;
    ?>
<style type="text/css">
a {
    color:<?php echo $data['link_color'];?>;
}
</style>
    <?php
}
```

### Hook

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_129259_enqueue_dynamic_css' );
```

### Using `style.php`

You can put your dynamic CSS in its own PHP file, then simply include it inside your callback. e.g.:

```
function wpse_129259_enqueue_dynamic_css() {
    // Include dynamic CSS file
    include( get_template_directory() . '/style.php' );
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_129259_enqueue_dynamic_css' );
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `wp_enqueue_style` means you have to add a .css format.
2. `wp_enqueue_script` means you have to add a .js format.

In this case, you want to add php format. You have to call in your main php file (index.php, header.php or etc) not in functions.php.

Use this `get_template_part()` or `require_once`. I advice you to put in header.php.

Comment: using require_once imports the file as is and not as a CSS file

Comment: you can follow like Chip Bennet said. It should be hook in. I want to tell you about the hook,  but I think it would be make you confuse.